# French paper translation help

Tags: discussion, languages

I am tranlating a mathematics education paper from French to English. Using Google translate and Bing translate is certainly helpful but is not perfect. I was wondering if I can ask the question related to translation in this site? If not what is the right place or site to go for it?

Any help are welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6690/translation-of-mathematical-questions

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6689/propose-new-tag-translation-request

Comment: Another related question: [How should I go about asking about translating a mathematical term from one language to another?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4527/how-should-i-go-about-asking-about-translating-a-mathematical-term-from-one-lang). And maybe other questions using the [meta-tag:languages] tag.